# MVC3 Json function hide specific Properties

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way in MVC3 to set what properties the Json function outputs?

ie. properties on my model have an attribute that tells the Json function not to output them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WEB.MVC.CONTROLLER.JSON);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) will do what you want. Just decorate whatever property you don't want serialized with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use anonymous method for that:

so instead of

```
return Json(it);
```

do

```
return Json(new {
  it.Name,
  CreatedAt = it.CreatedAt.ToString("D")
  // And so on...
});
```

this way you explicitly publish (map) set of attributes to the web which ensures that only allowed properties can be accessed from JSON.

If you don't want to Repeat Yourself, you can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) serializer with which you can customise how objects are serialised. (So you can create custom `HideAttribute` and take that into account).
With JSON.NET you will also need to write `Controller.Json` method replacement (`SmartJson` or so). But it should not be an issue I suppose.

Comment: hmmm, thats what I was afraid of. Was hoping I could just add an atribute and the Json function would be able to do it, like

[HideJson]public string Password { get; set; }

Comment: You actually can do it with a bit of effort. Use JSON.NET - updated the answer.